# Select data from oracle and draw a chart using Google charts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oracle, charts

I want to select data from oracle and draw the chart but when I run the my code nothing else drawed.new3.php:

```
$tns2 = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLUSTDB1)))";
if ($conn = oci_connect("CAKTAS","******", $tns2)) {
    echo "";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select wonum,STATUS, trunc( (sysdate-STATUSDATE) ) || 'd ' || trunc( mod((sysdate-STATUSDATE)*24,24) ) || ':' ||  trunc( mod( (sysdate-STATUSDATE)*24*60, 60 ) )  from maximo.WORKORDER_IT_VIEW where VFOPMGRGRP = 'IS_PRICHARHG' and STATUS <> 'COMPLETE' and STATUS <> 'CLOSE'");
    oci_execute($stid);
    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
    echo json_encode($row);
} else {
     die("could not connect to Maximo DB");
}
```

And it gives me correct array.
My html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kometschuh.de Tracker</title>
    <!-- Load jQuery -->
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Load Google JSAPI -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "new3.php", //my getting data php file
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var obj = window.JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

            var options = {
                title: 'Kometschuh.de Trackerdaten'
            };
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
                        document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);     
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in browser, I couldnt any chart

Comment: Is console has errors?

Answer (score 1):

Refer my blog: http://howdyharish.wordpress.com/2014/08/11/create-google-charts-using-php-and-oracle-database/#more-3

Here is the code.

Index.php

```
<?php

ini_set(‘max_execution_time’, 123456);

$conn=oci_connect(‘username‘,’password‘,’DBname‘);

If (!conn)

if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$query= oci_parse($conn, “select col1, col2 from tablename“);
oci_execute($query);

$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

array(‘label’ => ‘col1‘, ‘type’ => ‘string‘),
array(‘label’ => ‘col2‘, ‘type’ => ‘number‘),
);

$rows = array();
while($r = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
$temp = array();
//The below col names have to be in upper caps.
echo $r["COL1"];
$temp[] = array(‘v’ => (string) $r["COL1"]);

$temp[] = array(‘v’ => (int) $r["COL2"]);
$rows[] = array(‘c’ => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

//Use the line below to see the data in jason format
//echo $jsonTable;

//Use the below lines of code to see data in a HTML table

/*echo “<table border=’1′ >\n”;
echo “<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>\n”;
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
echo “<tr>\n “;
foreach ($query as $block) {
echo ” <td>” . ($block !== null ? htmlentities($block, ENT_QUOTES) : “&nbsp;”) . “</td>\n”;
}
echo “</tr>\n”;
}
echo “</table>\n”; */

?>

//In head section

<!–Load the Ajax API–>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”https://www.google.com/jsapi”></script&gt;
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js”></script&gt;
<script type=”text/javascript”>

google.load(‘visualization’, ‘1’, {‘packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
var options = {

title: ‘name of the chart‘,
is3D: ‘true’,
width: 1000,
height: 600,
fontName: ‘Times-Roman‘,
fontSize: 23,
hAxis: {textStyle: {
fontName: ‘Times-Roman‘,
fontSize: ‘25‘ }}
};

//To create a line chart
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(‘chart_div’));
chart.draw(data, options);

//To create a column chart

var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(‘chart_div2′));

chart2.draw(data, options);

}
</script>

// In body section

<!–this is the div that will hold the pie chart–>
<div id=”chart_div” ></div>
<div id=”chart_div2″ ></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just use json_encode, the PHP output needs to be in the format that the Google API will understand ([Google Documentation Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1)). So basically, you need to have some kind of function in php that transforms the OCI results into a JSON string readable by Google.

I have published a solution that works pretty well in my setup, other users might benefit from it. You can see my code on GitHub:

https://github.com/ernestomonroy/PHP-for-Google-Visualization-API

The php code looks as folows:

```
<?php
    /*
     * @author Ernesto Monroy <ehmizmg@gmail.com>
     * @version 1.0
     * This function takes the Connection Details and the SQL String and creates an two arrays, one for the column info
     * and one for the row data. This is then passed to the arrayToGoogleDataTable that builds and outputs the JSON string
     * 
     * Input for this is:
     *      $un: User Name
     *      $pw: Password
     *      $db: Connection String for the DB
     *              (e.g. '(DESCRIPTION=(CID=MyDB)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MyDB)))' )
     *              (tip, if you are running your PHP and Oracle Instance on the same server 127.0.0.1 should be used) 
     * 
     * WARNINGS:
     *      -I have not included any Oracle Error Handling
     *      -I have not included any row limit, so if your query returns an unmanageable amount of rows, it may become an issue for you or your web users.
     *FUTURE OPPORTUNITIES:
     *      -This functions only return type and label properties. If you want to use pattern, id or p (for styling) you can add a check  when looping through the columns
     *      and try to detect a particular column name that you define as the property (EG. if oci_field_name($stid, $i)=="GOOGLE_P_DATA" then ....)
     */
    function getSQLDataTable($un,$pw,$db,$SQLString){
        $conn=oci_connect($un,$pw,$db);
        $stid= oci_parse($conn, "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'");
        oci_execute($stid);
        $stid= oci_parse($conn, $SQLString);
        oci_execute($stid);
        $ncols = oci_num_fields($stid);
        $cols = array();
        $rows = array();
        $cell = array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
            $column_label  = '"'.oci_field_name($stid, $i).'"';
            $column_type  = oci_field_type($stid, $i);

            switch($column_type) {
                case 'CHAR': case 'VARCHAR2':
                    $column_type='"string"';
                break;
                case 'DATE':
                    $column_type='"datetime"';
                break;
                case 'NUMBER':
                    $column_type='"number"';
                break;
            }
            $cols[$i-1]=array('"type"'=>$column_type,'"label"'=>$column_label);
        }
        $j=0;
        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $ncols-1; $i++) {    
                switch(oci_field_type($stid, $i+1)) {
                    case 'CHAR': case 'VARCHAR2':
                        $cellValue='"'.$row[$i].'"';
                        $cellFormat='"'.$row[$i].'"';
                    break;
                    case 'DATE':
                        if($row[$i]==null){
                            $cellValue='""';
                            $cellFormat='""';
                        } else {
                            $cellValue=convertGoogleDate(date_create($row[$i]));
                            $cellFormat='"'.date_format(date_create($row[$i]), 'd/m/Y H:i:s').'"';
                        }

                    break;
                    case 'NUMBER':
                        $cellValue=number_format($row[$i], 2, '.', '');
                        $cellFormat='"'.$row[$i].'"';
                    break;


                } //end of switch
                $cell[$i]=array('"v"'=>$cellValue,'"f"'=>$cellFormat);  

            }   
            $rows[$j]=$cell;        
            $j++;
        }       
        arrayToGoogleDataTable($cols, $rows);
    }

    /*This function takes in the columns and rows created in the previous function and returns the JSON String*/
    function arrayToGoogleDataTable($cols, $rows) {
        //Convert column array into google string literal
        echo "{\n";
        echo "\t".'"cols"'.": [\n";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($cols)-1; $i++) {
            echo "\t\t{";
            $n=count($cols[$i]);
            foreach($cols[$i] as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
                    echo $arrayKey . ":" . $arrayValue;
                $n--;
                if ($n>0) {echo ",";}
            }
            echo "},\n";
        }
        //Last column without ending comma (},)
        echo "\t\t{";
        $n=count($cols[$i]);
        foreach($cols[$i] as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
                echo $arrayKey . ":" . $arrayValue;
            $n--;
            if ($n>0) {echo ",";}
        }
        echo "}\n\t]";

        //Now do the rows
        //Check if empty first
        if (count($rows)>0){
            echo ",\n\t".'"rows"'.": [\n";
            //For each row
            for($j = 0; $j < count($rows)-1; $j++) {
                echo "\t\t{".'"c":[';
                //For each cell
                for($i = 0; $i < count($rows[$j])-1; $i++) {
                    echo "{";
                    $n=count($rows[$j][$i]);
                    foreach($rows[$j][$i] as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
                            echo $arrayKey . ":" . $arrayValue;
                        $n--;
                        if ($n>0) {echo ",";}
                    }
                    echo "},";
                }
                //Last column without ending comma (},)
                $n=count($rows[$j][$i]);
                echo "{";
                    foreach($rows[$j][$i] as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
                        echo $arrayKey . ":" . $arrayValue;
                    $n--;
                    if ($n>0) {echo ",";}
                }
                echo "}]},\n";
            }
            //Last row
            echo "\t\t{".'"c":[';
            //For each cell
            for($i = 0; $i < count($rows[$j])-1; $i++) {
                echo "{";
                $n=count($rows[$j][$i]);
                foreach($rows[$j][$i] as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
                        echo $arrayKey . ":" . $arrayValue;
                    $n--;
                    if ($n>0) {echo ",";}
                }
                echo "},";
            }
            $n=count($rows[$j][$i]);
            echo "{";
                foreach($rows[$j][$i] as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
                    echo $arrayKey . ":" . $arrayValue;
                $n--;
                if ($n>0) {echo ",";}
            }
            echo "}]}\n";
            echo "\t]";
        }   
        echo"\n}";
    }
    /*This simply takes in a Date and converts it to a string that the google API recognizes as a Date*/
    function convertGoogleDate(DateTime $inDate) {
        $googleString='"Date(';
        $googleString=$googleString.date_format($inDate, 'Y').',';
        $googleString=$googleString.(date_format($inDate, 'm')-1).',';
        $googleString=$googleString.(date_format($inDate, 'd')*1).',';
        $googleString=$googleString.(date_format($inDate, 'H')*1).',';
        $googleString=$googleString.(date_format($inDate, 'i')*1).',';
        $googleString=$googleString.(date_format($inDate, 's')*1).')"';
        return $googleString;
    }
?>
```

For the rest of the implementation on Java and HTML check the git repo posted above

I know its a late reply, but still a top hit on Google and I have been asked the question a couple of times

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11988253)

Comment: @ThomasBormans Thanks for the tip. I added the code now to avoid the invalid links in the future